# find and replace string on a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a find and replace on strings

```
?version(.*) -> ?versionMyVersionHere
```

ex :

```
<script src="js/script.js?versionSomeVersionHere"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js?version"></script>

<script src="js/script.js?versionMyVersionHere"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js?versionMyVersionHere"></script>
```

I've tried something like :

```
sed -i -e "s/\?version/?versionMyVersionHere/g" index.html
```

But it append the text to the one already present...

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this !

Comment: In POSIX BRE in GNU sed, `\?` is a quantifier and `?` is a literal `?` char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's#\?version.*\"#\?versionMyVersionHere\"#g'
```

Demo :

```
$echo -e '<script src="js/script.js?versionSomeVersionHere"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js?version"></script>'  |  sed 's#\?version.*\"#\?versionMyVersionHere\"#g' 
<script src="js/script.js?versionMyVersionHere"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js?versionMyVersionHere"></script>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
sed -i 's/?version"/?versionMyVersionHere"/' index.html
```

**Details:**

- `?` doesn't need to be escaped in default BRE.
- Make sure to match trailing `"` in order to avoid matching partial word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to substitute all all occurrences of `?version` for `substitute` in your file `index.html`, then execute the following command:

```
sed -i 's/?version"/?versionMyVersionHere"/' index.html
```